# Compile - Optimization of function calls - does it matter?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, compile, scoping

I was surprised to see that, in the results of `CompilePrint` for a function made with `Compile`, calls to `Function`s seemed to be "actually" making a copy of the arguments, and perhaps-not optimizing-out the copies.

For example, compare the `CompilePrint` output of `compiledFunction` and `compiledExpression` below:

```
CompileSustitutable[vars_, body_] := 
 Hold[vars, body] /. Hold -> Compile

func = Function[x, Evaluate@Through@{# &, # + 1 &, #^2 &}@x]
expr = func[x]

With[
  {func = func},
  compiledFunction = Compile[{y}, func[y]];
  ];

compiledExpression = CompileSustitutable[{x}, expr];

CompilePrint@compiledFunction
CompilePrint@compiledExpression
```

The `compiledFunction` output is:

```
        R0 = A1
        I0 = 1
        Result = T(R1)0

1   R1 = R0
2   R2 = I0
3   R2 = R2 + R1
4   R3 = Square[ R1]
5   T(R1)0 = {R1, R2, R3}
6   Return
```

Whereas the `compiledExpression` output is:

```
        R0 = A1
        I0 = 1
        Result = T(R1)0

1   R1 = I0
2   R1 = R1 + R0
3   R2 = Square[ R0]
4   T(R1)0 = {R0, R1, R2}
5   Return
```

Although modern CPUs may perform their own optimization (which may make any Mathematica optimization a bit of a moot point, excepting any edge-cases), I don't like relying on unknown downstream processes.  Does anyone know if the "lowest-level code output by Mathematica" is basically what's shown in `CompilePrint`, as-shown?  I see that there are options like `CompilationTarget -> "C"`, so does a "normal/mainstream compiler" still do things like `inline`'ing function calls?

Is my `CompileSustitutable` function, which ostensibly saves argument copying, even worth the bother?

FYI: A much-less-elegant but interesting first attempt, demonstration the ability to bypass the "scoping" of `Compile`'s arguments is shown below -- I forget who to give credit to for the idea of using `Evaluate` in this manner:

```
With[
  {
   directMethod = Unevaluated[Evaluate[x]*2]
   },
  C1 = Compile[
    {Evaluate[x]},
    directMethod
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: `R1 = I0` is a type cast from 64 bit integer to 64 bit float (double). Yes, it does matter, though often only a bit. Anyways, you can get with from it by apply `N` to the expression before handing it over to `Compile`.

Comment: "Does anyone know if the 'lowest-level code output by Mathematica' is basically what's shown in CompilePrint, as-shown?" No, the actual code may divert considerbably from that. See ExportString[cf, "C"]` for that actual C/C++ code. And of course, the system compiler  (gcc, clang, MSVC,...)  will run over it and perform its own optimizations.

Comment: The many "copys" that _Mathematica_ generates would be generated by the compiler anyways to analyze the code structure. The `R1 = R0` is weird though. But the compiler will strip this out very likely.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher for the pointer to `ExportString[cf, "C"]`.  I'll post a response including the results of using this on a test function in a moment.  Regarding the use of `N[...]`, can you clarify how that would avoid the extra function calls / argument copying, using the example I posted for `Function[x, Evaluate@Through@{# &, # + 1 &, #^2 &}@x]`?  It seems to me that the argument wouldn't be known until you're running the compiled function, so I don't see how using `N[...]` at that point would reduce the overhead. But I'm tired ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I decided to get some quantitative results to this question -- through brute-force.  I decided to write my own version of `BorderDimensions` (calculates borders of a solid color around an image) using `Compile`.  It's non-trivial enough to actually demonstrate the point, but (I hope) small enough to post here.

Note that I'm aware that my version could be "tricked" if an image contains horizontal/vertical lines of the same color, but where each line doesn't have the same color as its adjacent line.  That's not the point for this question -- it's just a proof-of-concept.  Also, I think there's a bug in the "function-based" version (I ran it through some test images), but the point is that you can see a ton of `TensorCopy` operations in `CompilePrint`, and the results of `AbsoluteTiming` speak for themselves.

**The results confirmed that inlining functions yourself, *manually*, **does** actually result in performance boosts.**

I used Henrik Schumacher's suggestion of using `ExportString[cf, "C"]` to view the actual C-code generated, plus `AbsoluteTiming`.  Results: the version with function calls generated **double** as many lines of C-code, and took **more than double** time to execute, as measured by running 1000 iterations through a small test image and using `AbsoluteTiming`.

First, here is the test data:

```
testImgRaster = Rasterize@x
testImgData = 
  Rasterize[x] /. HoldPattern@Image[data__] -> List[data];
testImgDataArr = testImgData[[1]] // Normal;
```

Next, here is the benchmarking setup:

```
Style["PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions", Bold, Red]
codePaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions = 
  ExportString[PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions, "C"];
StringLength[codePaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions]
Do[PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions[testImgDataArr], {i, 0, 
   1000}] // AbsoluteTiming

Style["PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions", Bold, Red]
codePaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions = 
  ExportString[PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions, "C"];
StringLength[codePaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions]
Do[PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions[testImgDataArr], {i, 0, 
   1000}] // AbsoluteTiming

Style["Comparison - BorderDimensions", Bold, Red]
Do[BorderDimensions[testImgRaster], {i, 0, 1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Here are the benchmarking results:

```
PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions
15390
{0.447371,Null}

PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions
8898
{0.196994,Null}

Comparison - BorderDimensions
{0.180333,Null}
```

Finally, if you've read to here and want to see the actual code, here it is...

Note: I normally go way out-of-my-way to make small, concise, purpose-built functions.  But in addition to the performance benefits, I think I like the "look and feel" of the expression-based version better.  The style takes some getting-used-to, though.

Function-based version:

```
PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithFunctions = 
 Module[{PaddingCalculatorGenerator, PaddingCalculatorParams, numRows,
    numCols, PaddingCalculator, PaddingCalculatorInner},
  
  PaddingCalculatorGenerator[primaryRange_, secondaryRange_, 
    comparePart1_, comparePart2_] =
   Function[imageDataArgToCalculator,
    Hold@Do[
      Function[innerResult,
        If[innerResult == -1, 
         Return@Abs@(primaryRange[[2]] - primaryRange[[1]])]
        ]@
       Do[
        If[
         comparePart1@imageDataArgToCalculator == 
          comparePart2@imageDataArgToCalculator,(*Null*)-1, Return@-1],
        secondaryRange
        ],
      primaryRange
      ]
    ];
  
  PaddingCalculatorParams[numRows_, numCols_] =
   {
    {{rowIdx, 1, numRows, +1}, {colIdx, 1, numCols}, 
     Part[#, rowIdx, colIdx] &, Part[#, rowIdx, 1] &},
    {{rowIdx, numRows, 1, -1}, {colIdx, 1, numCols}, 
     Part[#, rowIdx, colIdx] &, Part[#, rowIdx, 1] &},
    {{colIdx, 1, numCols, +1}, {rowIdx, 1, numRows}, 
     Part[#, rowIdx, colIdx] &, Part[#, 1, colIdx] &},
    {{colIdx, numCols, 1, -1}, {rowIdx, 1, numRows}, 
     Part[#, rowIdx, colIdx] &, Part[#, 1, colIdx] &}
    };
  
  PaddingCalculator =
   ReleaseHold@
    Function[{imageDataArgToCalculators, numRows, numCols},
     imageDataArgToCalculators // 
        Apply[PaddingCalculatorGenerator] /@ 
         PaddingCalculatorParams[numRows, numCols] // Through // 
      Evaluate
     ];
  
  PaddingCalculatorInner = 
   With[{PaddingCalculator = PaddingCalculator},
    ReleaseHold@Function[imageDataArgToMain,
      Module[{numRows, numCols},
       numRows = Hold@Length@imageDataArgToMain;
       numCols = Hold@Length@First@imageDataArgToMain;
       Hold@PaddingCalculator[imageDataArgToMain, numRows, numCols]
       ]
      ]
    ];
  
  With[{PaddingCalculatorInner = PaddingCalculatorInner},
   Compile[{{imageDataArgToCompile, _Integer, 3}}, 
    PaddingCalculatorInner[imageDataArgToCompile]]
   ]
  ]
```

Expression-based version:

```
ReleaseHoldUnevaluated[expr_] := 
 ReplaceRepeated[HoldComplete[Unevaluated[expr]], Hold[x__] -> x] // 
  ReleaseHold

CompileSustitutable[vars_, body_] := 
 Hold[vars, body] /. Hold -> Compile

Module[{PaddingCalculatorGenerator, PaddingCalculatorParams, 
  PaddingCalculator, PaddingCalculatorInner},
 
 PaddingCalculatorGenerator[primaryRange_, secondaryRange_, 
   comparePart1_, comparePart2_] :=
  
  With[{primaryIndex = primaryRange[[1]], 
    primaryStart = primaryRange[[2]]},
   Hold@Do[ 
     Function[innerResult,
       If[innerResult == -1, 
        Return@Abs@(primaryStart - primaryIndex)] ]@
      Do[
       If[comparePart1 == comparePart2, Null, Return@-1],
       secondaryRange
       ],
     primaryRange
     ]
   ];
 
 ImagePart[row_, col_] = Hold@Part[imageData, row, col];
 
 PaddingCalculatorParams =
  {
   {{rowIdx, 1, numRows, +1}, {colIdx, 1, numCols}, 
    ImagePart[rowIdx, colIdx], ImagePart[rowIdx, 1]},
   {{rowIdx, numRows, 1, -1}, {colIdx, 1, numCols}, 
    ImagePart[rowIdx, colIdx], ImagePart[rowIdx, 1]},
   {{colIdx, 1, numCols, +1}, {rowIdx, 1, numRows}, 
    ImagePart[rowIdx, colIdx], ImagePart[1, colIdx]},
   {{colIdx, numCols, 1, -1}, {rowIdx, 1, numRows}, 
    ImagePart[rowIdx, colIdx], ImagePart[1, colIdx]}
   };
 
 PaddingCalculator =
  Hold[Module]
   [{numRows, numCols},
   Hold[CompoundExpression][
    Hold[numRows = Length@imageData],
    Hold[numCols = Length@First@imageData],
    PaddingCalculatorGenerator @@@ PaddingCalculatorParams
    ]
   ];
 
 PaddingCalculatorCompiledWithExpressions = 
  CompileSustitutable[{{imageData, _Integer, 3}}, 
   ReleaseHoldUnevaluated[PaddingCalculator]]
 ]
```